# W3DS in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

How can terrain data published using Geoserver's 2.4.0 wms and wfs services be viewed in 3d in WebGL enabled browsers? How to register/enable W3DS service in Geoserver 2.4 or above?